# How to fill out an empty matrix by incorporating some other matrices

Tags: r, matrix

My goal is that to fill in a big matrix with three other matrices of different size and let's call these matrices as C, D and E.

For example, let's denote the size of the big matrix B is 3N x 3N and let's partition this big matrix into another 3 by 3 size called "A" and I want to fill in this new partitioned matrix A  with the follow values:

- A_11 chunk is filled with the values of matrix C of size N by N.
- A_12 chunk is filled with the values of matrix D of size 1 by N.
- A_13 chunk is filled with the values of matrix E of size 1 by N.
- A_21 chunk is filled with the values of transpose(matrix C) of size N by 1.
- A_31 chunk is filled with the values of transpose(matrix D) of size N by 1.

The rest of the entries of matrix B will be 0.

Is there a built-in function in R to accomplish this goal?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack. Your question is a little bit broad, would you mind to add a small sample of your data and the expected output please. I understand what you want to do but some datas would help people so they can help you too.

Comment: Everything is populated through R, no real data, but sure.